# Add items to end of selectlist

Tags: c#

I need to manually add a few items to the end of a selectlist that was already created.  Here is the code for the selectlist:

```
m.StateList =
    new SelectList(svc.GetStates(user.Login, user.Password), "Key", "Value");
```

Can someone tell me how I can add a few more items to that list? I have done plenty of searching.

Comment: Please stop making the single line edit, and reference this question on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104086/guidelines-for-code-editing-especially-horizontal-scrolling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Create a list from the result of GetStates
var states = svc.GetStates(user.Login, user.Password).ToList();
// Add whatever you like
states.Add(...);
// Create the SelectList
m.StateList = new SelectList(states, "Key", "Value");
```

Comment: Simple, I was thinking I had to create the SelectList first.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ's `Concat()` method:

```
svc.GetStates(user.Login, user.Password).Concat(...)
```

Comment: I prefer this method because it's a little more concise. And, LINQ.